# Upgrading Ubuntu Python 3.8.2 to Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu that has Python 3.8.2. I am also starting university soon, and the professor would like us students to use Python 3.8.5. So far, I have only found instructions on how to update Python 2.x.x or 3.x.x to Python 3.8.x and not 3.8.x to 3.8.x, so I was wondering how should i go about the process in my case?

Comment: I don’t think it will be a problem if you use 3.8.2 instead of 3.8.5.

Comment: `sudo apt install --upgrade python` should work, no? Same as any other program?

Comment: You can check https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html to see the differences between 3.8.2 and 3.8.5. 3.8.2 should work fine, and if you encounter any problems, you can check that list to see if an already patched bug is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is simple and does not necessarily require 100% usage on the *terminal*, and there is practically no difference between an `x.x.x` to an `x.x.y`, but to *install*

Acess this [link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tar.xz)

First, let's remove the current version with:

```
sudo apt remove python
```

then

Unzip in your preferred folder

Open the folder in the terminal and type: `./install-sh`

Be happy

Comment: @Justin I would advise you not to do this and stick with the version that is provided by the Ubuntu package manager. Adding a custom installation separately will lead to trouble sooner or later. Ask the professor if you can use 3.8.2. I bet you will be fine.

Comment: I also agree that there is probably little to no difference between 3.8.2 and 3.8.5, thus meaning that I can get away with 3.8.2. I also thought that adding another version of python could wreck havoc on my OS (maybe some processes require 3.8.2 specifically), and it was probably just a recommended suggestion, not a hard requirement, to use 3.8.5 on my professor's part. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JustinYue Sorry for taking too long to answer, but as @ mkrieger1 said, it can cause problems, but to avoid this, uninstall the current python and install the one desired by the installer, obs: from 3.8.2 to 3.8.5 it doesn't change practically anything, so you can continue with 3.8.2 quietly